# How to slow down this rotation

Tags: unity, c#

My goal here is simple. I am making a top down shooter kind of game, and I want the player to simply rotate in one axis, towards where the mouse is on the screen. I got it working, but it rotates so fast that everything is out of control. The following method is called in Update() on my player's game object

```
void RotatePlayer()
{

    var targetPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 100);

    targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(targetPosition);

    targetPosition.y = transform.position.y * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.LookAt(targetPosition);

}
```

That rotates in the direction of the mouse, but like I said it rotates so fast that you cannot control it.

As you can see I tried to multiply by delta time, but that did not seem to do anything. Also, changing that last parameter of "100" to a lower number also does not do anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `float rotateSpeed` variable from `0.00f` to `1.00f` and multiple your `targetPosition.y` by that after `Time.deltaTime`.

I can't test this right this very moment, but I'm fairly certain that should work.

Comment: That still did not work, but I did find another way to accomplish what I was trying to do.  `code    void RotatePlayer()
    {               
        var xDeg = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * m_TurnSpeed;

        transform.Rotate(0f, xDeg, 0.0f);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to do this,

```
void RotatePlayer()
{               
    var xDeg = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * m_TurnSpeed;

    transform.Rotate(0f, xDeg, 0.0f);
}
```